# Arranging VARCHAR data into Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, pivot

My data is in a SQL table in the following format (I have about 20 different answers per user_id):

```
USER_ID     ANSWER
--------------------------
1           CAR
1           10-20 miles 
1           SALES 
2           TRAIN
2           0-10 miles
2           TEACHER
```

I would like to create a view in PostgreSQL where all the data is shown according to User ID

```
USER_ID     ANSWER1     ANSWER2        ANSWER3
-----------------------------------------------
1           CAR         10-20 miles    SALES
2           TRAIN       0-10 miles     TEACHER
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your data contain no ordering info do tell answer1 from answer2 from answer3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is great example of not relational data (the semantic depends on row number), although the data are saved in relational database. You cannot to make relational data from not relational inside relational database. There is not any mechanism how to do this transformation safely. Theoretically, if physical order of your data is same like in your picture, then you can write queries (but you should not to use `ORDER BY` clause, because it can change order, because your data doesn't hold necessary data for correct ordering):

You need function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.x_transformed()
 RETURNS TABLE(user_id integer, rowno integer, answer character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare r record; 
prev_user_id int;
begin
  for r in select * from x
  loop
    if user_id is distinct from r.user_id then
      rowno := 1;
    else
      rowno := rowno + 1;
    end if;
    user_id = r.user_id;
    answer = r.answer;
    return next;
  end loop;
end;
$function$
```

This function can add missing order information to relation. It is pretty ugly solution, but your input data are in very unhappy format, and there is not possible any clean solution (based on relational algebra):

```
postgres=# select * from x_transformed();
┌─────────┬───────┬─────────────┐
│ user_id │ rowno │   answer    │
╞═════════╪═══════╪═════════════╡
│       1 │     1 │ CAR         │
│       1 │     2 │ 10-20 miles │
│       1 │     3 │ SALES       │
│       2 │     1 │ TRAIN       │
│       2 │     2 │ 0-10 miles  │
│       2 │     3 │ TEACHER     │
└─────────┴───────┴─────────────┘
(6 rows)
```

Now, the transformation to the requested format is easy (search pivoting):

```
select user_id,
       max(answer) filter (where rowno = 1) as answer1,
       max(answer) filter (where rowno = 2) as answer2,
       max(answer) filter (where rowno = 3) as answer3
 from x_transformed() group by user_id;
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────────┬─────────┐
│ user_id │ answer1 │   answer2   │ answer3 │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════════╪═════════╡
│       2 │ TRAIN   │ 0-10 miles  │ TEACHER │
│       1 │ CAR     │ 10-20 miles │ SALES   │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────────┴─────────┘
(2 rows)
```

The main problem is in format of your input data. It can be good enough for file and application processing, but are terrible bad for storing (and processing) in relation database. The relation (or the table) is heap (not file).

With knowledge of Postgres's internals, you can ensure expected order although you use some relational operations. You can use internal implicit column `ctid`. `ctid` is an unique address of row. This will not work on other databases, and it will not work on older Postgres releases:

```
select user_id,
       max(answer) filter (where rowno = 1) as answer1,
       max(answer) filter (where rowno = 2) as answer2,
       max(answer) filter (where rowno = 3) as answer3
  from (select user_id,
               answer,
               row_number() over (partition by user_id
                                  order by ctid) as rowno
          from x) s
 group by user_id
 order by user_id;
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────────┬─────────┐
│ user_id │ answer1 │   answer2   │ answer3 │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════════╪═════════╡
│       1 │ CAR     │ 10-20 miles │ SALES   │
│       2 │ TRAIN   │ 0-10 miles  │ TEACHER │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────────┴─────────┘
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Also - I thought postgres results are not ordered (e.g. if the table is vacuumed or other internal housekeeping happens then the implicit order can change) so even with this clever approach there's no guarantee that the rowno will be consistent between queries.

Comment: When you do just read without any other operation, and there is not any other parallel read, and the data was imported from file without any updates and deletes, then it can work, but sure - it is very fragile. The relational table is not file, and this is very good example of bad design.

Comment: @PavelStehule can you please explain how does your code ensure that vehicle type always gets row 1, and job always gets 3 and the miles 2. It is not so clear how is that working fine

Comment: Essentially he's depending on the row ordering that postgres stores when it initially writes the rows down in the page files. There are a lot of assumptions, but generally speaking postgres should insert them one after the other and read them in the same order they are written.

Comment: If we edit/delete rows postgres may vacuum and rewrite the rows, destroying the ordering. If our query is complex (e.g. group by), it can reorder the implicit order. But if we stick to simple reads and don't touch the data, it should stay in the same order that it was written in. As we've both noted, this is very bad/fragile and a column should be added that can be ordered by.

Answer (score 0):

fiddle for regex: https://regex101.com/r/oUgYbj/1

This would only work assuming you always have the same order for q1,q2,q3
I believe your data should have some field to order it by in order to avoid confusion something like a new column: Question_rank and then it showing the value
1 for Car and Train and value 2 for miles and value 3 for Jobs i.e Sales / Teacher.

This way we can have Question_rank in the order by clause as second column

```
with data as(
select
user_id,
STRING_AGG(answer,',') as all_answers
from table
group by 1
Order by id
)
select
user_id,
REGEXP_MATCHES (all_answers,'^([^,])+') AS answer_1,
REGEXP_MATCHES (all_answers,'\d+(-)\d+\s+\w+') AS answer_2
REGEXP_MATCHES (all_answers,'[^,]*$') AS answer_3
from data
```

Comment: It is not fully safe, because `GROUP BY` can change an order of row

Comment: that doesn't matter regex is looking for a different  pattern each time and not focusing always on one specific sequence: see https://regex101.com/r/xvVrGz/1

Comment: Unfortunately, it is random - `group by` clause can do rehashing or resorting by `user_id`. For small data it uses hashing, so then there is not reason why aggregation will be processed in different older. But for larger dataset, the postgres can use sort based aggregation - in this case based on user_id, but the order inside group depends on quick sort processing.

Comment: for that order by can be added i believe

Comment: `order by` doesn't help - there is not any colum for sorting

Comment: we can first select everything with order by id and in the second cte do the string_concat and then regex what do you think ?

Comment: This is wrong - the `ORDER BY` can break order inside group, because there is nothing that ensure requested order. It is really good example, and task for training thinking. There is not any clause that ensure order based on physical order. If I do sort by user_id, then I get sorted user_id, but I can get unsorted answer column.

Comment: getting unsorterd answer column would be fine because regex will just look for all the pattern individually. It doesn't matter which string will be the first one in string_concat()

Comment: i see what you mean now

Comment: This is principal problem - you cannot to do relational data from not relational by relational algebra - there is not enough information, and the tools based on relational algebra cannot to use an order information, and cannot to ensure an order. The relational databases are not designed for this. This task can be safe if your data are stored in file - and the reading from file ensure an order, but the postprocessing of data in file can be pretty complicated if groups are not continual (from parallel clients).

Comment: row_number() from windows function would also not work right ? due to the order by column  missing

Comment: it should not work too - it needs grouping and sorting.

Comment: yes I can see the missing column relevant for order by

Comment: @PavelStehule how does your code ensure that the row id will be the same for all  vehicle type / job and miles. If the arrangement is different then it will have the same issue as i have, no ?

Comment: when you do only sequential scan without any other operations, then there is not necessity to reorder data, and you will get data in physical order, but maybe you can ensure - because there is an possibility to use `ctid`.